# Restarting thread fails to pause

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I've got a tricky thread question for an Android app. I'm creating a Thread in `onCreate()` and interrupting it in `onDestroy()`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Handler mHandler;
    private Thread mThread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message inputMessage) {
                Log.d("test", "Message: " + inputMessage.toString());
            }
        };

        mThread = new Thread(myRunnable);
        mThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("test", "onDestroy");
        mThread.interrupt();
    }
```

The Runnable sends a message to the UI thread via the Handler `mHandler`, setting the message's `arg1` to a increasing integer.

```
    private Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Log.d("test", "Start runnable");

            int count = 0;
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {               
                count++;

                // Simulate a long task
                for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) ;

                // Tell UI thread the count
                Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                msg.arg1 = count;
                mHandler.sendMessage(msg);    
            }

            Log.d("test", "Thread is interrupted");
        }
    };
}
```

Logcat shows the Runnable starting, messages received by the UI thread with the increasing number (1, 2, etc.) that are spaced about a second apart, and the thread terminating when the activity is destroyed:

```
05-10 20:10:35.269 3236-3268/my.threadingdemo D/test: Start runnable
05-10 20:10:37.200 3236-3236/my.threadingdemo D/test: Message: { when=0 what=0 arg1=1 }
05-10 20:10:37.934 3236-3236/my.threadingdemo D/test: Message: { when=0 what=0 arg1=2 }
05-10 20:10:38.694 3236-3236/my.threadingdemo D/test: Message: { when=-1ms what=0 arg1=3 }
05-10 20:10:40.172 3236-3236/my.threadingdemo D/test: Message: { when=0 what=0 arg1=4 }
05-10 20:10:40.394 3236-3236/my.threadingdemo D/test: onDestroy
05-10 20:10:41.981 3236-3268/my.threadingdemo D/test: Thread is interrupted
```

The problem is this: If I restart the app (press the Recents button and select the app or start it from the launcher), the Thread is restarted as expected, but Logcat gets flooded with messages. The for loop doesn't seem to be pausing the Runnable any more.

Here's a brief snippet from Logcat showing the first 7 messages are received all in the same second (20:10:48):

```
05-10 20:10:48.280 3236-3308/my.threadingdemo D/test: Start runnable
05-10 20:10:48.315 3236-3236/my.threadingdemo D/test: Message: { when=-33ms what=0 arg1=1 }
05-10 20:10:48.318 3236-3236/my.threadingdemo D/test: Message: { when=-38ms what=0 arg1=2 }
05-10 20:10:48.319 3236-3236/my.threadingdemo D/test: Message: { when=-39ms what=0 arg1=3 }
05-10 20:10:48.320 3236-3236/my.threadingdemo D/test: Message: { when=-39ms what=0 arg1=4 }
05-10 20:10:48.870 3236-3236/my.threadingdemo D/test: Message: { when=-584ms what=0 arg1=5 }
05-10 20:10:48.871 3236-3236/my.threadingdemo D/test: Message: { when=-585ms what=0 arg1=6 }
05-10 20:10:48.872 3236-3236/my.threadingdemo D/test: Message: { when=-586ms what=0 arg1=7 }
```

I don't understand why the for loop appears to be unable to slow the messages down.  Replacing the for loop with `Thread.sleep(1000)` will cause a 1 second delay between messages, but shouldn't the for loop be adequate?  It's weird that the for loop slows things down the first time the app is started but not afterwords.

Comment: I think what you want is to use `onResume` and `onPause` instead of `onCreate` and `onDestroy`.

Comment: @Onik, the 2nd time I start the app is when the Logcat is flooded with messages. The problem is occurring *before* I close the app the 2nd time.

Comment: @m0skit0, the behavior is identical, regardless of where the thread is started and interrupted.

Comment: @Onik, I understand you're talking about closing the app a 2nd time, but in my posting I didn't say anything about closing it a 2nd time... I closed it once, restarted it, then was flooded with messages. If I close the app a 2nd time by pressing the Back button, onDestroy is called.

Comment: Now I get it :) The timestamp of `logcat` is just a time when log gets printed, not the time of execution. Don't pay much attention to it, there are dozens of processes all over the system posting their logs at the "same time". What matters is `Message`s [when](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html#getWhen()). As to "simulating a long task" it seems to be carried out way too faster than a second. I recommend to log `System.currentTimeMillis()` both before and after the `for` loop.

Comment: @Onik, I think you can still pay attention to the timestamps in this situation because of the stark contrast between the runs. However, I did log the time before and after the for loop like you suggested. On 1st run the delay is roughly 1000 millis, on the 2nd run it is consistently 0.

Comment: @Onik, I've been running this on an emulator, and I tried running the app on a physical device to see the difference.  On a physical device the for loop delays about 600 ms the 1st run, 100 ms on the 2nd run. Weird.